# How do I convert @ClassRule into an Extention?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, junit5, wiremock

Im currently transitioning my WebFlux Application to use junit 5 from v4, my gradle.properties has

```
testImplementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
exclude group : 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}
```

along with standalone wiremock dependency

```
testImplementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-wiremock:${springCloudVersion}"
```

I am trying to figure out a way to load classRule in junit 5 or convert it into an extension, seems like the most code reduced approach.

Has anybody faced these issues and resolved this? I know there is `WireMockExtention.class` i can extend but I couldn't find the artifact for this, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

JUnit Jupiter has limited support for [JUnit 4 Rules](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-rule-support), but that does not include support for `@ClassRule`.

Thus, if you have a custom class rule you've written for JUnit 4, your best bet is to rewrite it using the `BeforeAllCallback` and `AfterAllCallback` extension APIs in JUnit Jupiter. You can then [register your extension](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration) via `@ExtendWith` or `@RegisterExtension`.